# blank page before the title page

Tags: blank-page

What should I do to get rid of the first blank page before the title page? The code of the file is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the Title of a Standard \LaTeX\ Article}
\author{J. A. Smith\thanks{This is for making an acknowledgement.}
\\The University of Miskolc, Hungary}
\date{February 24, 2002}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a sample document which shows the most important features of the Standard
\LaTeX\ Journal Article class.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\noindent The front matter has various entries such as\\


\appendix

\section{The First Appendix}

The appendix fragment is used only once. Subsequent appendices can be created
using the Section Section/Body Tag.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get a blank page with your code.

Comment: I would suggest to move `\title` etc before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I tried moving \title etc tages before \begin{document}; it didn't work. I am using Texniccenter 2.2 with MikTex 2.9.

Comment: Did you try **exactly** the code you show above or is this only a "my-actual- code-is-different-but-it-shouldn't-matter-example"?

Comment: Yes I tried the exact code as shown in this page.

Comment: I test your code with MikTeX 2.9 (WinEdt editor) and I didn't get a blank page with your code. I also move `title` etc before `\begin{document}` and I get the same result as before.

Comment: Check for error messages in the log file. Such issues are often due to a BOM marker.

Answer (score 1):

No blank page for me.

> I copied and paste your exact code -- see screen capture animation.

[image]